# How do you suppress Facebook apps canvas scrollbars in Firefox 7*+?

Tags: css, facebook, api, canvas

I have built a FB app and am unable to suppress the canas scrollbars in FF browsers.  Chrome, IE and Safari are fine.

The guilty style seems to be a master style set in the FB CSS giving all body tags to overflow-y:scroll.  So even though there is nothing outside of the canvas area and I've set the canvas to dynamically resize, FF still reserves the scrollbar space.  Compounding the problem, reserving the scrollbar space encroaches on 760 pixel canvas.

I have checked the api and there is no support for administering the FB styles.  The app in question is http://apps.facebook.com/plus-size-clothing/

Answer (score 0):

Setting my app's body `overflow` to hidden and calling `FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();` worked for me.

**Javascript:**

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId  : 'YOUR-APP-ID',
    status : true, /* check login status */
    cookie : true, /* enable cookies to allow the server to access the session */
    xfbml  : true  /* parse XFBML */
  });

  FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(); /* Automatically sets canvas size */
};
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  /* your styles here... */
}
```